# What did King David do to the people of Ammon after he captures the city in Shmuel 2 at the end of Chapter 12

Tags: mussar-ethics, army-military-war, samuel-shmuel-book-of, king-david, violence

What does this actually mean? 
Was it that King David put them to work or he literally tortured them?
where it says:
31.
And the people that were therein he brought forth and he put them under saws, and under harrows of iron, and under axes of iron, and he made them pass through the brick kiln; and so he did to all the cities of the children of Ammon. And David and all the people returned to Jerusalem.        לאוְאֶת הָעָם אֲשֶׁר בָּהּ הוֹצִיא וַיָּשֶׂם בַּמְּגֵרָה וּבַחֲרִצֵי הַבַּרְזֶל וּבְמַגְזְרֹת הַבַּרְזֶל וְהֶעֱבִיר אוֹתָם בַּמַּלְבֵּן (כתיב בַּמַּלְכֵּן) וְכֵן יַעֲשֶֹה לְכֹל עָרֵי בְנֵי עַמּוֹן וַיָּשָׁב דָּוִד וְכָל הָעָם יְרוּשָׁלָםִ:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Rashi* and other commentators say it means he tortured them. *Ralbag* explains that this was to dissuade other peoples from fighting the Jews. (See the context starting at, say, 10:1.)